# Adding body classes with Wordpress PHP function

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I am using a script to dynamically add classes to the body tag. I am trying to add an additional fixed (non dynamic class). I simply need to add a class of loading the body.

This is the function that creates the body classes

```
function add_slug_to_body_class( $classes ) {
    global $post;
    if( is_home() ) {     
      $key = array_search( 'blog', $classes );
      if($key > -1) {
        unset( $classes[$key] );
      };
    } elseif( is_page() ) {
      $classes[] = sanitize_html_class( $post->post_name );
    } elseif(is_singular()) {
      $classes[] = sanitize_html_class( $post->post_name );
    };

    return $classes;
  }
```

And I need to add a class of 'loading' in addition to whatever classes are dynamically generated.

I cannot simply add the classes to the body tag because they are replaced with the newly generated classes:  `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`

How do I include an extra class in this php function?

Comment: Couldn't you just put `$classes[] = "loading";` before you return the array?

Comment: of course, thank you, make an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just put:

```
$classes[] = "loading";
```

before you return the array. This will be added as a body class when:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

is run.

The full documentation on the `body_class()` function is here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class